# golang add passphrase to key.pem

Tags: go, ssl

I am trying to add a passphrase to an already existing key.pem. (I know the key is an RSA private key.)

```
    // Read the certificate file content
    certPEM, err := ioutil.ReadFile(certFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    keyPEM, err := ioutil.ReadFile(keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    keyBlock, rest := pem.Decode(keyPEM)
    if keyBlock == nil {
        return errors.New("failed to decode PEM block containing private key")
    }
    if len(rest) > 0 {
        log.Println("Warning: Additional data found after PEM block")
    }

    block := &pem.Block{
        Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        // Type:    "ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY",
        Headers: keyBlock.Headers, // Preserve existing headers
        Bytes:   keyBlock.Bytes,
    }

    block, err = x509.EncryptPEMBlock(rand.Reader, block.Type, block.Bytes, []byte(password), x509.PEMCipherAES256)

    keyPEM = pem.EncodeToMemory(block)

    var cert tls.Certificate
    cert, err = tls.X509KeyPair(certPEM, keyPEM)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err loading keyPair: ", err)
        return err
    }
```

But I got an err when loading the key with the cert

`err loading keyPair:  tls: failed to parse private key`

Thanks

Comment: tls.X509KeyPair does not support encrypted keys.